# Searching box from a list of xml?

Tags: objective-c, xml, uitextfield

Using `objective c` , and `UITextField`, i am trying to set a basic search engine.
So when user starts to type a word, he will get a list of words from an xml file (or other such as json) , and as he continue typing ,the list will be changed to adapt . Much like google search box .

1. I guess i dont have to invent the wheel and a searching algorithm from an xml file has already be done- but i couldn't find one .
2. Regarding the UI elements needed, i guess a search box with a built in list is something that already there also ?

thanks .

Comment: Who are these people , i really want to know them, first down vote then closing such a relevant question. I guess that jealously is a popular thing among people here. At least be a man and say why are you vote to close this. Do you have a similar question with an answer? does this problem is not relevant enough ? what it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of tutorials online you should have a look at if you want to do this

Here are some about making a search:

[AppCoda Search Bar](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/)

[Ray Wenderlich Search View Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift)

Here are some about parsing XML and JSON:

[AppCoda JSON Parse](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/)

[AppCoda JSON & XML Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/)

[Ray Wenderlich XML Parse](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

I recommend you recommend that you read through these and other online documentation/tutorials and decide how you want to code your search engine.

My advise for building this is to have a UITextField for the user to type into and then have a UITableView to display the results. You should parse the XML to a NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray and search using the user's input.

Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: I am trying to work with a csv files but thanks that would be great for a start.

Comment: @Curnelious for CSV i recommend this: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser i have used it before and it worked perfectly